# Scrolling div horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I make this scroll left or right using navigation button?

```
<div class="slider-wrap">
 <div class="slide-wrap">
    <div class="slider-slide-wrap"></div>
    <div class="slider-slide-wrap"></div>
    <div class="slider-slide-wrap"></div>
 </div>
</div>
 <div id="slider-left" class="slider-nav"></div>
 <div id="slider-right" class="slider-nav"></div>
```

JS

```
  $("#slider-left").click(function(){
   alert("< clicked.");
 });
 $("#slider-right").click(function(e){
        alert("> clicked.");

    $('.slide-wrap').scrollLeft(5000);
 });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rAb3V/165/)

Comment: When adding a Fiddle, please add your code to your question too. I corrected it

Comment: You need to scroll `.slider-wrap` not `.slide-wrap`: https://jsfiddle.net/rAb3V/168/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting the wrong `<div>`. Note the selector: `$('.slider-wrap')` (not `.slide-wrap`).

```
$("#slider-left").click(function () {
    $('.slider-wrap').animate({
        scrollLeft: 0
    }, 200);
});
```

I have used `.animate` because you get visual feedback about what's happening (*so I think using animate is better for UX*). This would work equally well with `.scrollLeft()` though:

```
$("#slider-left").click(function () {
    $('.slider-wrap').scrollLeft(0);
});
```

See it working in a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mm2jphzp/2/)**